# Applescript - Returns different values as Script vs Application ...?

Tags: fonts, applescript, status

I got a little bit of code that looks for missing fonts.
When it's a script it returns "installed" or "not available"
When it's an application it returns «constant ****fsIn» or «constant ****fsNA»

I suppose a workaround would be to just make it look for the fsIn instead, but I'd still like to understand what is going on here...

```
tell application id "com.adobe.InDesign"
    tell active document
        set fontStatus to (status of every font)
        repeat with s in fontStatus
            display dialog (s as string)
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display dialog` belongs to Standard Additions which is in a different scope.
Try to set the constant to a variable in the scope of Indesign

```
tell application id "com.adobe.InDesign"
    tell active document
        set fontStatus to (status of every font)
        repeat with s in fontStatus
            set fontStatusString to s as string
            display dialog fontStatusString
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

That's normal. Apple events use "four-char codes", not human-readable names. 
When you run a script in Script Editor, AppleScript already has the application's terminology loaded (since its needed to compile AS scripts from source code) so can use it to convert those codes back to human-readable names.

When you save the AS script as a standalone app, it's already compiled so the app's terminology isn't loaded by default. You can either use a conditional block:

```
repeat with aConstantRef in fontStatus
    set theConstant to contents of aConstantRef
    if theConstant is installed then 
        set constantName to "installed"
    else if theConstant is not available then
        set constantName to "not available"
    ...
    else -- catch-all in case you miss any
        set constantName to theConstant as string
    end if
end repeat
```

or you can force AppleScript to load the app's terminology at runtime by including a `run script` command that compiles a 'dummy' script targeting that app:

```
run script "tell application id \"com.adobe.InDesign\" to (not available)"
```

after which that terminology should be available to your main script as well.